# Approximating a function using its integral

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation

**Question**:
Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R \in C^{1}, \forall \delta>0:$ 
$$F_\delta = \frac 1{2\delta}\int^{x+\delta}_{x-\delta} f(t) \, d(t)$$

in $[a,b]$ prove that $\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists \delta>0\text{ s.t. }\forall x\in[a,b] |F_{\delta}(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$

**What we did**
F is the antiderivative of f. We know it exists because a continuous function is Riemann integrable.
based on Newton Leibnitz, the basic theorem of integral math and Lagrange theorem:
$|F_\delta(x)-f(x)|=| \frac 1{2\delta}(F(x+\delta)-F(x-\delta)-f(x))|$
for some $c\in [x+\delta,x-\delta]$

$=|F'(c)-f(x)|=|f(c)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$
from the fact that $f(x)$ is continuous then when $|x-c|<\delta \Leftarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$

Is this solution correct?

Comment: What is $F$? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I made an edit explaining it

Comment: It looks perfectly fine.